# Encrypt database connection string in ASP.Net Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am currently encrypting, decrypting db connection string in web.config using Data Protector class of ASP.Net 1.1, But what are the other methods to achieve this and i should be able to provide a Key for encryption and decryption.

Thanks in advance for solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to provide a Key for encryption (for example, when you want to use the same encrypted configuration file on many computers in a Web farm) you can use the [RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider Class](http://RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider%20Class).

You can encrypt your web.config with the following statement:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" C:\<path to your website>
```

The aspnet_regiis tool is located in

> %WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\

The RSA machine key will be stored in

> \Documents and Settings\All Users\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

After running this tool you will see that your web.config connectionstrings section is encrypted. If you use the correct machine key on your production machines ASP.NET can decrypt the connectionstrings on its own and everything should work out of the box.